# How to output an element that has occured or listed multiple times in an array list from a user input

Tags: java

How to output an element (content of index) that has been repeated by the user input multiple times with out using the collections, hashmap or treemap method?

**I am looking for a linear or you could say a mathematical approach rather than a ready command approach, could someone help please?**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
 

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (true) {
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        if (input == -1) {
            break;
        }
        arrayList.add(input);
    }
    System.out.println("search for? ");
    for (int loopValue = 0; loopValue < arrayList.size(); loopValue++) {

        int input2 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input2 + " is at index " + arrayList.indexOf(input2));
    }
```

/
a sample output should look similar to the following:

```
input user:
10
20
20
30
30
40
50
if -1 is inputted, the user will exit the loop

Number you are searching for in an array list?: the user again input the desired number 30

number 30 is at index 3
number 30 is at index 4
```

how can I show the indices of a frequent number just like above^?

Comment: Move `int input2 = scanner.nextInt();` to before the `for` loop so you only input the value once. Then inside the loop: `if (arrayList.get(loopValue ) == input2) System.out.println(input2 + " is at index " + loopValue );`

Comment: Thank you @Johnny Mopp, you have answered my question accurately, but I have a question: why do I assign the arraylist to the loopValues inside the loop and not the old input value that I have added and collected in the while loop?

Comment: `loopValue` is the index used to access the `arrayList` items.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, how did the loopValue become an index without using .add to the array to become an index of an array list?

Comment: In your example, you add 7 items to the list. So, `arrayList.get(0) = 10; arrayList.get(1) = 20; arrayList.get(2) = 20; arrayList.get(3) = 30;`, etc. You can replace the numbers I typed with any integer variable. So, for example, when `loopValue = 3` then `arrayList.get(loopValue) = 30;`.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could do:

```
System.out.println("search for? ");
int input2 = scanner.nextInt();
for(int i =0; i<arrayList.size();i++){
    if(arrayList.get(i)==input2){
            System.out.println(input2 + " is at index " + i); //e.g. 30 is at index 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lilpercy, I will also direct my question to as it is to the other person named Johnny. Why do I assign the loop value which is (i) in your code to the arraylist instead of the input that has been collected and added in  my while loop code?

Comment: So i is the loop value therefore it increments after each run, we are saying we want to get the value within the arraylist at index 0, then index 1, index 2 etc. so that we can retrieve all the values in the array list and then we compare the value at that index to the input from the user. If we used the input from the user to get the value within the array e.g. arrayList.indexOf(input); it would just return 1 value and if we did arrayList.get(input); we would get an out-of-bounds error as we are saying get the value at index 30 which in this example does not exist.